# What is -> operator in Java/JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, operators

Looking into an open source project in JavaFX I found this lines:

```
@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn;
@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn;
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    // Initialize the person table with the two columns.
    firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
    lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());
 }
```

I never saw the "->" operator before. What is it?

The signature of setCellvalueFactory is:

```
setCellValueFactory(Callback< TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures< S,T>,
                    ObservableValue< T>> value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arrow token in your code is part of a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Some say it's the biggest feature that came with Java 8.

One example use case is to improve code readability. Instead of an anonymous class

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
});
```

you could write the same as lambda expression:

```
btn.setOnAction(
    event -> System.out.println("Hello World!")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are not using Java 8 this token is used by IntelliJ IDE to make visually shorter your methods.